# Determine RAM clock timing in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, memory, wmic, memory-timings

How would I determine the RAM clock timing in Windows 10 using wmic memoryChip or related commands in command prompt or else a related, built-in tool.

I'm not that trusting of third-party software that taps into my system's hardware, so please don't suggest that as a solution.

Comment: it doesn;t look like neither the wmic memoryChip or W32_PhysicalMemory classes has this information, which makes sense since timings a negotiated by the SPD, not the chip itself. TBH, timings aren't important at the windows level; if the SPD can't negotiate them, 'the RAM just doesn't appear to the OS at all.

Comment: I've added some edits to clarify, but in short I meant to say "latency" not "clock timing"... admittedly terminology is not my cup of tea, which is the main issue there!

In terms of why latency is important, it is because I need to match two already installed ram modules to utilize dual channel ram.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This can be easily done within PowerShell using the following commands:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_physicalmemory | Format-Table Manufacturer,Configuredclockspeed,Devicelocator,Capacity,Serialnumber -autosize
```

This will give the following as output:
[image]

---

You can also get this through Command line using the following command:

```
wmic memorychip get Capacity, MemoryType, Speed, DeviceLocator
```

..which would give the following output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use wmic MemoryChip.

Example command:

```
wmic MemoryChip get BankLabel, Capacity, MemoryType, TypeDetail, Speed
```

where Speed is the parameter you need.

Comment: This doesn't give the latency, though.

Answer (score 0):

After digging deeper, my original intention (to use already existent single channel memory and match using latency, speed, and size to a new memory set) is a seriously bad idea.  There are several instances of individuals, in hindsight including myself, having bad experiences doing this.  In my case, several years ago, a slight mismatch of latency on dual channel ram caused the memory upgrade for a PC to be essentially unusable.

If someone absolutely needs to pull the latency, there are third-party tools that I am aware of (CPU-Z, for example), that I personally would rather avoid but may be good enough for someone else.  That said, for my purposes, I think I would advise that if your purpose for seeking the latency is the same as mine was, just don't.

Answer (score 0):

Single channel and dual channel rating doesn't matter so much to the dimms. technically, although it is often advertised as such, there is no such thing as "dual channel memory dimms" or "single channel.." etc. It all depends on whether or not your CPU/Motherboard supports dual or single channel config, you use the same dimms no matter what. The dimms probably have the latency spec printed on them. If not, you can google the model number and find more of that particular model. I do not recommend mixing and matching dimms, generally it just doesn't work. Also, ram timings are adjusted in BIOS on your motherboard, not in windows.

To summarize - if you want to tighten the timings and adjust voltage of your RAM, use BIOS. if you want to add ram to an empty slot, buy the EXACT SAME model that you already have, same capacity, same timing, etc. or it likely wont work. Or, most easily and effectively, look up what ram your cpu/mobo can run, and just buy all new ram.